Trying to display "completed tickets per agent per day" in PBI matrix using Dax
Currently, the matrix shows the distinct count of the "Reference" column for each agent for each day using the "Created date" column. What I want is to display the amount of numbers in the "Reference" column that no longer appear, compared to the previous day. Here is the context:
The "Reference" column is populated with numbers that are used as reference numbers. Think of it as a support ticket number. Example; Agent A has 10 tickets (all with a Reference number) as of Monday May 1st, one of which has reference number "12345". Agent A completes reference number "12345" on Monday May 1st and therefore the reference number does not appear on report for Tuesday May 2nd. Tuesday report is added and Power BI is refreshed with the Tuesday data. I want to create a Dax measure that checks to see if reference number "12345" from Monday May 1st is still there on Tuesday May 2nd, and if not, show "1" on May 2nd in matrix (i.e. 1 ticket was completed by Agent A).
In other words, Agent A completes 5 tickets (each with different, unique reference number) on Monday May 1st, the reference numbers don't show on report for Tuesday May 2nd, and matrix shows "5" for May 2nd column.
I haven't even gotten to the point where I compare the current day to the previous day reference numbers yet. I was trying to create an expression to simply show the difference of the distinctcount and couldn't even get that to work properly. I have attached an image (censored agent names for privacy) and will paste the code I was using as well:
Completed References = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX('SPJ Productivity'[Date created]) 
VAR PreviousDate = CALCULATE(MAX('SPJ Productivity'[Date created]), FILTER(ALL('SPJ Productivity'), 'SPJ Productivity'[Date created] < CurrentDate))
RETURN 
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('SPJ Productivity'[Reference]), FILTER('SPJ Productivity', 'SPJ Productivity'[Date created] = CurrentDate)) - CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('SPJ Productivity'[Reference]), FILTER('SPJ Productivity', 'SPJ Productivity'[Date created] = PreviousDate))



Add sample data and your current presentation. Then you can show what is your required presentation.

Based on your description " What I want is to display the amount of numbers in the "Reference" column that no longer appear, compared to the previous day.",
EXCEPT (
'Tickets',
FILTER('Tickets',[CloseDate]=TODAY()-1)
)
